# How to Click a follow button on instagram dynamically using javascript from followers list of any other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this on console. But its not working. I want to click the follow button dynamically by my javascript code. I know that I can use InstPy. But I want develop my code.

Code:

First open the follower list of any account on instagram and then run this code.

```
var list=document.querySelectorAll(".PZuss li")<br>
list[2].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()
```

---

Output = undefined

What should I do so that my function start following the account when the program is executed.

Answer (score 1):

So what are you trying to accomplish? Follow the 3rd user of the follower list?

For me `document.querySelectorAll(".PZuss li")[2].querySelector('button').click()` works just fine.

Comment: Yes you understood the problem right but Its not working fine for me....! When I am practising on the google developers tool console the click operation is not performed.? Can u please help me through this. You also tried this script on google developers tool console.